# Can't boot from USB after bundled install

Tags: grub2, live-usb, 15.10, lenovo

On a carbon X1, I attempted to install 15.10 via usb boot disk. The install progressed until it came to a solid purple screen. On reboot, I now see this

[image]

Not panicing myself (pun intended), it appears my options were to just reinstall or use a live USB.

I ensured that secure boot was off and legacy was allowed

[image]
[image]

However, on reboots, pressing F12, and selecting the USB boot option, I'm now stuck in an endless cycle that just comes back to this screen.

[image]

It seems that no matter how I try to format the USB drives, nothing seems to be recognized. I've tried UNETBOOTIN and Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator on a working install of 15.10.

**Question: What should I do next? How do I dig myself out of this?**

Comment: Follow up: A know bug is in U15.10's start up creater. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/1499746

Comment: If you want, you could mark one of the answers as the Top Answer (I can't remember what it's called but it means the answer is at the top with a green tick on it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Kudos to Dominic's answer. Upvoted. This answer is a pure *nix method. )

It's a bug! Specific, it [was reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/1499746) that both USB Startup Creator and UNetbootin were effected. This [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator/+bug/1499746/comments/5) led me to **[mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)**

I used mkusb with a newly downloaded lubuntu iso.

[image]

[image]

Status: It's working.

Comment: PS: There's also another alternative called dd where you can wipe a USB Clean with a new parition containing contents of the selected ISO added afterwards.

Comment: So then, how did you run the Program in the first place when your PC was still Crashing? (Or did you just use another one?)

Comment: Had access to other  nix machines. I don't have a lot of Windows around me.

Answer (score 1):

Try RUFUS for Windows, this USB Installer is one of a kind in that it can also UEFI Bootloader Tag a USB Drive that it's writing the ISO to meaning that the drive is bootable from UEFI.

PS: Download Rufus at: https://rufus.akeo.ie/

PS: It needs Windows to run; from my experience, IT WILL NOT WORK ON WINE OF VIRTUAL MACHINES.

PS: Darn, it really is broken, by the looks of it, you have no init!!

Comment: Thank you. We'll give this a go. It's a new install so not really worried about saving the failed install. At this point, I'd just be happy for this thing to boot off a live USB.

Comment: I've not yet tried this, as I'm tracking down a workable Windows machine. I'd love to have a *nix focused method